# How customize wordpress for intranet purpose?

Tags: wordpress, intranet

I want to use wordpress for intranet portal/blog purpose.

So i want, there should be no link to internet from wordpress.

No traffic should be to internet from my intranet.

Like there are many link are in wordpress: help,resister,forget password etc.

Please some plug-in or theme for this purpose.

Comment: and your programming question was?

Comment: Your problem is not a coding one, this question would be better served on ServerFault

Answer (score 1):

There's not much to do here. No need for a plugin.

Just install Wordpress on a server reachable only locally (with a local host name), and specify that host name as the root URL of your blog.

You may have to set up a local mail server to deliver E-Mail, or use an external one for the purpose. That's the only real snag that I can see.

Also, you may want to turn off the various "Look for updates" functions that WordPress has in its backend. But if the server you install the blog on doesn't have Internet access, that problem will solve itself.

Comment: @Rahul if you fear that your local server is reachable from the Internet, you may want to ask a question specifically about that on serverfault.com. You can configure Apache in a way that denies access to all IPs except for the local one. This is not a Wordpress issue.